# Series I DB2 Using common table expressions (CTE) with Values...Into in a SQLRPGLE program

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpgle

GM, I am writing a SQLRPGLE program that will use DB2 SQL to generate XML files in the IFS. I was able to test the theory using standard SQL (select....) and generate the XML file in the IFS using values..into.

When I tried to expand this using CTE's with the values..into, I get a syntax error

```
SQL0104 Token WITH was not valid. Valid tokens: (
```

My question is OK to use CTE's with Values..into? and if so, what am I doing wrong? (code below). Also. I know there are other, maybe more suitable ways to do this. But this was something I recently came across and wanted to try it out to see if it is some thing to add to list of techniques. But with that error creeping in, I may need to move on to something else...

```
   exec sql VALUES(
          With Stylemaster as ( 
          SELECT CPY007, DIV007, SEY007, KYS007, CC#007, SST007, STD007,
             FAB007, LEN007, SCT007, CGP007, DLV007, RPR007, PC1007, PC3007,
             STS007,  DCD007, SDA007, SDB007, SDC007, SDD007, SDE007, SDF007,
             SDG007, PI1007, PI2007, PI3007, PI4007, PI5007, PI6007, PI7007,
             PI8007, CDEC07, SCALE, INVALID,  IDX, COLOR, SKU100, SKU200,
             SKU300, SKU400,CPY, SINDEX, SZS, DES, S01, P01, N01, B01, ASZ, AS2
          FROM ((SELECT CPY007, DIV007, SEY007, KYS007, CC#007, SST007, STD007,
                 FAB007, LEN007, SCT007, CGP007, DLV007, RPR007, PC1007, PC3007,
                 STS007, DCD007, SDA007, SDB007, SDC007, SDD007, SDE007, SDF007,
                 SDG007, PI1007, PI2007, PI3007, PI4007, PI5007, PI6007, PI7007,
                 PI8007, CDEC07, SCALE, INVALID, IDX, COLOR
             FROM DRLMFILES.pst007 t,
                 LATERAL (VALUES (SSC007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 01, 1), 01),
                       (SSC007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 02, 1), 02),
                       (SSC007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 03, 1), 03),
                       (SSC007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 04, 1), 04),
                       (SSC007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 05, 1), 05),
                       (SSC007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 06, 1), 06),
                       (SSC007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 07, 1), 07),
                       (SSC007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 08, 1), 08),
                       (SSC007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 09, 1), 09),
                       (SSC007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 10, 1), 10),
                       (SSD007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 11, 1), 01),
                       (SSD007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 12, 1), 02),
                       (SSD007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 13, 1), 03),
                       (SSD007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 14, 1), 04),
                       (SSD007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 15, 1), 05),
                       (SSD007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 16, 1), 06),
                       (SSD007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 17, 1), 07),
                       (SSD007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 18, 1), 08),
                       (SSD007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 19, 1), 09),
                       (SSD007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 20, 1), 10),
                       (SSE007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 21, 1), 01),
                       (SSE007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 22, 1), 02),
                       (SSE007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 23, 1), 03),
                       (SSE007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 24, 1), 04),
                       (SSE007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 25, 1), 05),
                       (SSE007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 26, 1), 06),
                       (SSE007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 27, 1), 07),
                       (SSE007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 28, 1), 08),
                       (SSE007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 29, 1), 09),
                       (SSE007, SUBSTR(SZO007, 30, 1), 10))
                       AS D(SCALE, INVALID, IDX),
                 LATERAL (VALUES (CL0107),(CL0207),(CL0307),(CL0407),(CL0507),
                                 (CL0607),(CL0707),(CL0807),(CL0907),(CL1007),
                                 (CL1107),(CL1207),(CL1307),(CL1407),(CL1507),
                                 (CL1607),(CL1707),(CL1807),(CL1907),(CL2007),
                                 (CL2107),(CL2207),(CL2307),(CL2407),(CL2507),
                                 (CL2607),(CL2707),(CL2807),(CL2907),(CL3007),
                                 (CL3607),(CL3707),(CL3807),(CL3907),(CL4007),
                                 (LEN007))
                         AS E(COLOR)
          WHERE SCALE <> ' ' AND INVALID <> 'X' AND COLOR <> ' ') S
          JOIN (SELECT CPY, SZS, DES, SINDEX, S01, P01, N01, B01, ASZ, AS2
             FROM DRLMFILES.PGI538 T,
                 LATERAL (VALUES (CPY538, 01, SZS538, DES538, S01538,
                                  P01538, N01538, B01538, ASZ538, AS2538),
                                 (CPY538, 02, SZS538, DES538, S02538,
                                  P02538, N02538, B02538, ASZ538, AS2538),
                                 (CPY538, 03, SZS538, DES538, S03538,
                                  P03538, N03538, B03538, ASZ538, AS2538),
                                 (CPY538, 04, SZS538, DES538, S04538,
                                  P04538, N04538, B04538, ASZ538, AS2538),
                                 (CPY538, 05, SZS538, DES538, S05538,
                                  P05538, N05538, B05538, ASZ538, AS2538),
                                 (CPY538, 06, SZS538, DES538, S06538,
                                  P06538, N06538, B06538, ASZ538, AS2538),
                                 (CPY538, 07, SZS538, DES538, S07538,
                                  P07538, N07538, B07538, ASZ538, AS2538),
                                 (CPY538, 08, SZS538, DES538, S08538,
                                  P08538, N08538, B08538, ASZ538, AS2538),
                                 (CPY538, 09, SZS538, DES538, S09538,
                                  P09538, N09538, B09538, ASZ538, AS2538),
                                 (CPY538, 10, SZS538, DES538, S10538,
                                  P10538, N10538, B10538, ASZ538, AS2538))
                   AS STYLE(CPY, SINDEX, SZS, DES, S01, P01, N01, B01, ASZ, AS2)
                   WHERE S01 <> ' '
       ORDER BY CPY, SINDEX, SZS, DES, S01, P01, N01, B01, ASZ, AS2)
       SC ON S.CPY007 = SC.CPY AND S.SCALE = SC.SZS AND S.IDX = SC.SINDEX)
       JOIN TRLMFILES.PDIV000 DD on S.CPY007 = COMP00 and S.DIV007 = DIVI00

       GROUP BY CPY007, DIV007, SEY007, KYS007, CC#007, SST007, STD007,
       FAB007, LEN007, SCT007, CGP007, DLV007, RPR007, PC1007, PC3007, STS007,
       DCD007, SDA007, SDB007, SDC007, SDD007, SDE007, SDF007, SDG007, PI1007,
       SZS, PI2007, PI3007, PI4007, PI5007, PI6007, PI7007, PI8007, CDEC07,
       SCALE, INVALID, IDX, COLOR, S01, SKU100, SKU200, SKU300, SKU400, CPY,
       SINDEX, SZS, DES, S01, P01, N01, B01, ASZ, AS2

       ORDER BY CPY007, DIV007, SEY007, KYS007, CC#007, SST007, STD007,
       FAB007, LEN007, SCT007, CGP007, DLV007, RPR007, PC1007, PC3007, STS007,
       DCD007, SDA007, SDB007, SDC007, SDD007, SDE007, SDF007, SDG007, PI1007,
       SZS, PI2007, PI3007, PI4007, PI5007, PI6007, PI7007, PI8007, CDEC07,
       SCALE, INVALID, IDX, COLOR, S01),

       UPCMaster as
       (SELECT (DIGITS(INF004) ||
                DIGITS(MFG004) ||
                DIGITS(UPC004) ||
                DIGITS(CKD004)) as UPC,
                SKU004  ,
                FAB004 as Fabric,
                LEN004 as Length,
                SIZ004 as Size,
                CASE WHEN SIZ004 = 'PPK' THEN LEN004
                     WHEN FAB004 = 'PR' THEN LEN004
                     WHEN FAB004 = 'EA' THEN LEN004
                     ELSE CLR004
                END  as ColorCode,
                SSC004 as Sizescale,
                IDX004 as Index from DRLMFILES.PUP004
        WHERE SKU004 =INT(2307502))
           SELECT
           XMLElement(name "Style",
              XMLAttributes(CPY007 as Company,
                            DIV007 as Division,
                            CC#007 as SKU_number,
                            Color as Color ),
                 XMLForest(CPY007 as Company,
                           DIV007 as Division,
                           SEY007 as Seasonyear,
                           KYS007 as Season,
                           CC#007 as SKU_number,
                           SST007 as Style,
                           STD007 as Style_desc,
                           FAB007 as Fabric,
                           LEN007 as Length,
                           CGP007 as Group_Code,
                           DLV007 as Delv_code,
                           RPR007 as Sugretprc,
                           PC1007 as standprice,
                           PC3007 as euro_cosdt,
                           STS007 as pack_hang,
                           DCD007 as style_dsc,
                           SDA007 as styledesc2,
                           SDB007 as styledesc3,
                           SDC007 as styledesc4,
                           SDD007 as styledesc5,
                           SDE007 as styledesc6,
                           SDF007 as styledesc7,
                           SDG007 as styledesc8,
                           PI1007 as footupper,
                           PI2007 as footsole,
                           PI3007 as htscode,
                           PI4007 as packinstr4,
                           PI5007 as packinstr5,
                           PI6007 as packinstr6,
                           PI7007 as packinstr7,
                           PI8007 as packinstr8,
                           CDEC07 as citesstyle,
                 XMLAGG( XMLELEMENT(name UPCNUMBER,
                            XMLForest(Index,
                            UPC,
                            Fabric,
                            Length,
                            Size,
                            ColorCode ))
                         ORDER BY UPC, SIZE) as "UPCS" ))
              FROM StyleMaster AAA join UPCMaster BBB on
                    CC#007 = SKU004 and
                    Color = ColorCode and
                    SZS = SizeScale and IDX = Index
              GROUP BY CPY007, DIV007, SEY007, KYS007, CC#007, SST007, STD007,
                       FAB007, LEN007, SCT007, CGP007, DLV007, RPR007, PC1007,
                       PC3007, STS007, DCD007, SDA007, SDB007, SDC007, SDD007,
                       SDE007, SDF007, SDG007, PI1007, PI2007, PI3007, PI4007,
                       PI5007, PI6007, PI7007, PI8007, CDEC07, COLOR

              ORDER BY CPY007, DIV007, SEY007, KYS007, CC#007, SST007, STD007,
                       FAB007, LEN007, SCT007, CGP007, DLV007, RPR007, PC1007,
                       PC3007, STS007, DCD007, SDA007, SDB007, SDC007, SDD007,
                       SDE007, SDF007, SDG007, PI1007, PI2007, PI3007, PI4007,
                      PI5007, PI6007, PI7007, PI8007, CDEC07, COLOR)
               INTO :Outfile ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next time, consider putting together a simpler version that demonstrates the issue...

```
  exec sql
    values (with cte as (select current_timestamp(8)
                         from sysibm.sysdummy1
                        )
             select * from cte
            )
      into :ts;
```

Same error, which surprises me...but reading the [documentation for VALUES INTO](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzvalinto.htm) it does say...

> **row-fullselect**
>   A fullselect that returns a single result row. The result column values are assigned to each corresponding variable. If the result of the fullselect is no rows, then null values are assigned. An error is returned if there is more than one row in the result.

A *fullselect* is not the same as a *select-statement* which allows CTEs per [this page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzsubsel.htm)

> **fullselect**
>   The fullselect is a component of the select-statement

Consider building a view for the *select-statement* then your embedded code becomes simply:

```
exec sql
  values (select * from myview) into :outfile;
```

Comment: For a little more clarification, you can also look at the select-statement page [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzintsel.htm).  Notice that a CTE uses a fullselect but is not part of one.

Comment: Charles, sorry about that. In the future I'll minimize the code when possible. I had thought that the full code would be more informative, as i was so lost as what was the issue.

Comment: I'm still puzzled though.

When I did my initial test (without a CTE (was much simpler then) I did not have this issue. The code (since it is an XML object) only returns a single row. Which I thought would satisfy the single-row requirement. Let me do some more testing....